# self.size is (320,480) even if my app is in landscape

Tags: swift, landscape, screen-size

If I print self.size i get (320,480) but it should be (480,320) because my app is in landscape this is how I go to my main view:

```
var playScene = Menu(size: self.size)
let skView = self.view! as SKView

skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
playScene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
playScene.size = skView.bounds.size
skView.presentScene(playScene)
```

**Edit:** I've found that on an Iphone 5s the self.size is (568, 320) so the problem is only on iphone 4s or on IOS 7

Answer (score 0):

The sizes of views aren't updated until UIKit runs layout. That happens after `viewDidLoad` returns. So if that code is in `viewDidLoad`, you're checking too soon.  Look at the size in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` or `viewDidAppear:`.

Comment: I am not using UIKit i am using SpriteKit

Comment: `SKView` is a subclass of `UIView`. `UIView` is a part of UIKit.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to use this function to get the right screen size for the device i am using:

```
func screenSize() -> CGSize {
    var screenSize: CGSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
    if ((NSFoundationVersionNumber <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1) && UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation)) {//If ios 7

        return CGSizeMake(screenSize.height, screenSize.width);
    }
    return screenSize;
}
```

And i replace my code to change the view to:

```
var playScene = Menu(size: self.size)
let skView = self.view! as SKView

skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
playScene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
playScene.size = screenSize()
skView.presentScene(playScene)
```